# A custom debug visualizer stopped working in VS 2019. VS is unable to load it anymore

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, debuggervisualizer

I have a custom debug visualizer in my project that derives from the `DialogDebuggerVisualizer` class. I am using the `DebugVisualizerAttribute` to annotate the classes that can be supported by the visualizer. Visual Studio 2019 shows the visualizer option during debugging, but when I choose to use open this custom visualizer, I get the following error:

> Unable to load the custom visualizer.
>
> The debuggee-side visualizer type
> 'MyProjectName.DebugVisualizers.MyCustomVisualizer'
> could not be resolved. This may be due to an older version of
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll being loaded in the
> debugged process. Please ensure that there are no references to older
> versions of this DLL in the debugged process and instead use the
> latest reference to build against.

This used to work fine until recently. It seems like one of the recent updates to VS 2019 is now causing it to fail to load.

My project correctly references the "**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll**" assembly, which is the location that the documentation mentions to use.

So not sure what is causing this issue. Has anyone experienced a similar problem and know how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to re-add `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll`, then check if the version in Properties window.

Comment: I added the reference to the assembly again. The version # remained the same as before - 16.0.0.0. I am using VS version 16.10.4.